# Why is GA Experiment crushing my whole report?

Tags: google-analytics, tracking, a-b-testing

Until yesterday, we had a clean reporting of our content urls that looked like:

```
/men/shirts/shirt-with-extended-lines?color=12988
```

But then we activated an experiment and since then we just see this in our reports:

[image: Google Analytics Screenshot]

That is kinda wired, because the [document location parameter](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/protocol/v1/parameters#dl) `dl` is correct in the ga collect call.

As soon as I stopped our GA experiment, all URLs were good again.

It looks like our first test (where URL were ok) had a parameter

`Web page to experiment` : `<domain>.<tdl>/catalog/produc/`

and the experiment with URL problem had this url set to

`Web page to experiment` : `<domain>.<tdl>`.

But why does this cause my problem?!